# Jquery donut chart customisation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-widgets

Hi I am trying to replicate the below image:

[image: Donut Chart]

I have found a plugin which will almost replicate and I have tried to customise it to style and add the inner text.  I cannot seem to style it as below.  I have tried to apply the color property to the series but this is not working.  I am not sure if the colorScheme property is overriding but I am stuck at the moment.

Here is what I have tried: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ux68H/261/)

and the code is below:

```
var data = [
    {Responses: "Accepted", Share: 33.3},
    {Responses: "Unresponded", Share: 26.5},
    {Responses: "Rejected", Share: 25.4}
]

// prepare chart data as an array
var source =
{
    datatype: "array",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'Responses' },
        { name: 'Share' }
    ],
    localdata: data
};

var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, { async: false, autoBind: true, loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { alert('Error loading "' + source.url + '" : ' + error); } });

// prepare jqxChart settings
var settings = {
    title: "Geoff's Birthday Party",
    description: "",
    enableAnimations: true,
    showLegend: false,
    legendPosition: { left: 520, top: 140, width: 100, height: 100 },
    padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
    titlePadding: { left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
    source: dataAdapter,
    colorScheme: 'scheme13',
    seriesGroups:
        [
            {
                type: 'donut',
                showLabels: false,
                series:
                    [
                        {
                            dataField: 'Share',
                            displayText: 'Responses',
                            labelRadius: 100,
                            initialAngle: 15,
                            radius: 130,
                            innerRadius: 90,
                            centerOffset: 0,
                            formatSettings: {decimalPlaces:1 },
                            color:'#00000'
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
};

// setup the chart
$('#jqxChart').jqxChart(settings);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you put your choice of text inside de pie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own color scheme:

```
$.jqx._jqxChart.prototype.colorSchemes.push({ name: 'myScheme', colors: ['#006688', '#bbbbbb', '#7777777'] });
```

and then reference it in the settings object instead of 'scheme13':

```
colorScheme: 'myScheme',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aPK98/3/

Unfortunately they don't support callout/leader lines for each of the values or showing the total in the middle. If you need that you would need to manually draw them using SVG.

Comment: Excellent Thank you! Was not aware of colour schemes